# How to deploy strapi on google cloud platform?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, strapi

I'm trying to deploy strapi on google cloud app engine (standard env) but I keep getting a 500 server error. I googled all over but no guides have been written on how to successfully deploy strapi on AE.

I tried the suggestions on this thread: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/2146
So I have:

- the gcp-build script to install dependencies
- an entrypoint in app.yaml to start strapi
- my database.json and server.json in strapi are updated

But it does not seem to work for me. I keep getting the following error:
[image: log]

I tried googling that error "app/invalid" but I can't seem to find anything about that.

I also gave the flex env a spin but that failed as well (without a proper error).

This is my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: nodejs10
instance_class: F2
service: admin
entrypoint: node_modules/strapi/bin/strapi.js
env_variables:
  DATABASE_HOST: "host"
  DATABASE_PORT: 27017
  DATABASE_NAME: "db"
  DATABASE_USERNAME: "name"
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: "pw"
  DATABASE_SRV: true
  DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE: "admin"
  DATABASE_SSL: true
  NODE_ENV: "production"
  PORT: 1337
```

This is my package.json (important parts):

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "strapi": "node_modules/strapi/bin/strapi.js",
    "gcp-build": "node node_modules/strapi/lib/utils/post-install.js && cd admin && npm run setup"
  }
...
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
```

production database.json:

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "strapi-hook-mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "client": "mongo",
        "host": "host",
        "port": 27017,
        "database": "db",
        "username": "name",
        "password": "pw",
        "srv": true
      },
      "options": {
        "authenticationDatabase": "admin",
        "ssl": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And finally this is my server.json file:

```
{
  "host": "https://admin-dot-ootje-website.appspot.com",
  "port": 1337,
  "production": true,
  "proxy": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "autoReload": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "cron": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "admin": {
    "autoOpen": false
  }
}
```

I would expect that this works from the getting started guides in AE but it would seem I'm missing something. Does someone know what that error means? Did someone manage to already deploy strapi on AE?

If I get it working I'd like to add it to strapi docs or medium post for other people to find it easier than I did :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem provide from server.json file.

This configuration works on my side :

```
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": "${process.env.PORT || 1337}",
  "production": true,
  "proxy": {
    "enabled": false      
  },
  "autoReload": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "cron": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "admin": {
    "autoOpen": false
  }
}
```

I'm working on a new configuration file in order to have the auth provider working... and some other features. But this first version is working for me.

I keep you update of my search if you need.

**## Update 1 ##**

I found the good configuration for GCP in production mode.
I share it if anyone else need it :

```
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": "${process.env.PORT || 1337}",
  "production": true,
  "proxy": {
    "enabled": true,
    "ssl": true,
    "host": "[project-name].appspot.com",
    "port": 443
  },
  "autoReload": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "cron": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "admin": {
    "autoOpen": false
  }
}
```

I use **flexible** environment on GCP, but this will work in **standard** mode I think.

Thanks,

Comment: thanks for the reply! I'm going to try this out, could you share your app.yaml? Do you use the gcp-build script?